# Tooltip is not showing right

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I want to put a tooltip in my website, but it doesn´t working and I think that it´s because I have `overflow` on `td`. The tooltip should be on top of text, but it end at start of another `td`. Thank you for help.

```css
.akce {
  height: 120px;
}

.akce td:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.akce td {
  font-size: 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.akce a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
}

.tooltip span {
  display: none;
}

.tooltip:hover {
  z-index: 21
}

.tooltip:hover span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  overflow: none;
}
```

```html
<tr class="akce">
  <td></td>
  <td><a href="https://www.facebook.com/events/1958747484336759/" class="tooltip">Ukázková lekce Čchi-kung - 8 kusů brokátu<span>Ukázková lekce Čchi-kung - 8 kusů brokátu</span></a></td>
  <td><a href="https://www.facebook.com/events/119239315466281/">Ukázková lekce Čchi-kung - 8 kusů brokátu</a><br>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/events/1763815880581348/">Ukázková lekce Tai Chi Čchi-kung - Žena na své cestě života</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Why is that even a table to begin with? Doesn’t look much like you are representing actual tabular data here ...

Comment: Because I did something like calendar. So I did it with table.

Answer (score 0):

I've added **top** and **left** values to the *.tooltip:hover span* in your code snippet.
You already correctly positioned it absolute, but it doens't have any values set.

You can fully fill the td by also adding right and bottom with 0, but I guess it depends how exactly you want to position the tooltip.

Hope this helps!

```css
.akce {
  height: 120px;
}

.akce td:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.akce td {
  font-size: 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.akce a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
}

.tooltip span {
  display: none;
}

.tooltip:hover {
  z-index: 21
}

.tooltip:hover span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  overflow: none;
  left:0;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<tr class="akce">
  <td></td>
  <td><a href="https://www.facebook.com/events/1958747484336759/" class="tooltip">Ukázková lekce Čchi-kung - 8 kusů brokátu<span>Ukázková lekce Čchi-kung - 8 kusů brokátu</span></a></td>
  <td><a href="https://www.facebook.com/events/119239315466281/">Ukázková lekce Čchi-kung - 8 kusů brokátu</a><br>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/events/1763815880581348/">Ukázková lekce Tai Chi Čchi-kung - Žena na své cestě života</a></td>
</tr>
```